# How to get all child name of a parent element using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

i'm using webdriver with java and i try to get the list of all parent nodes in a web page.
the goal is to :
1st- get all parents name of an element
2nd- compare the new list with an existing list
in order to detect if a new element was added or deleted or modified in the web page.

So my html code is:

```
<div class="list"> 
 <ul>
    <li>
        <h4>
            Content
        </h4>
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="summary"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="file"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="text"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="graph"></li>
  </li>
     <li>
      <h4>
```

so i tried this ,

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/d‌​iv/div[1]/select")));
int i =select.getList();
System.out.print("Options ="+i);
```

i don't get any list of nodes name.

Can anyone suggest a solution.
Thx

Comment: I don't see a `<select>` tag in your HTML, but I see it in your XPath. Which elements do you want to get and watch for changes, the `<li>` elements?

Comment: Yes i want the list of li elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` is used for dropdowns.  You're dealing with a `<ul>`.

This approach should work better:

```
WebElement ulList = driver.findElement(By.className("list"));

List<WebElement> values = ulList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

int i = values.size();
System.out.print("Options = " + i);
```

Comment: This is the core, yes. It gets slightly harder to make the change detection work, though. You can compare `size()` of the original list and the new one to detect additions and removals, but not one addition combined with one removal. And you can't detect changes. To do that, you'd actually need to store the data from the nodes and compare that. Anyway, this answer is the way to go.